# any way to backup apt-get update

Tags: apt, updates

I am using ubuntu 11.10 lts. whenever I screw up my system , I want to restore it using live cd. but apt-get update takes long time.my internet connection is poor. 
any way to backup those apt-get updates and install them in New os?

Comment: Ok, but I think the question is the same for 12.10 and my answer is usable for any version which ist supported with updates.

Comment: This question needs a clean up, but it is not the same as the dupe it was linked to.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own repository on another local machine.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LocalAptGetRepository

Comment: is there any way to backup those apt get updates in flash drive ?

Comment: I dont undertand the question. If you setup a "server" for your updates there are saved local and you can save it where you want - on a HDD or a flash drive if it fits the size. But you need another mashine to do this. Its not possible to do this locally on your PC that you like to reinstall.